# JavaScript | Data duplication problem when using add new data by map

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hello**
At first, I apologize for the catchy title, but; I got to the point where I don't know what to do when I think about fetching an array with important values ​​into another array based on values ​​called value
Anyway, I will explain my words in code

```
let logs = [
{
    "label": "Category - New",
    "value": "categoryNew",
    "emoji": ""
},
{
    "label": "Category - Updata",
    "value": "categoryUpdata",
    "emoji": ""
},
{
    "label": "Category - Delete",
    "value": "categoryDelete",
    "emoji": ""
}
]
let arr = ["categoryDelete","categoryNew"];
logs.map((m) => { if(arr.includes(m.value)){ m.default = true } })
```

The idea from the previous code, that it fetches an array logs and then I use map to add a new modification provided that the value is similar to the array arr.
The data is executed and the embedded logs are shown defautl:true.
The code works without problems but when the code is executed again with the same values ​​listed previously.

My problem now is that I want to delete the new mods inside map and basically rely on what is only inside let arr , let logs

Comment: Do you want to keep the original `logs` and create new ones with the modification, like in `const logsModified = logs.map(m => ({...m, ... (arr.includes(m.value) ? { default: true } : {})}));` ?

Comment: Or you just want to delete the modifications you made on `logs` like `logs.forEach(m => {delete m.default})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the initial loop through logs. Then you need to loop through your "default" array. It checks if the value of your log is equal to the value in your default array. If it is it adds default to the log object, then pushes it to the temporary j array. Then all the values are included into logs by using the spread operator .

```
let logs = [
  {
    label: "Category - New",
    value: "categoryNew",
    emoji: ""
  },
  {
    label: "Category - Updata",
    value: "categoryUpdata",
    emoji: ""
  },
  {
    label: "Category - Delete",
    value: "categoryDelete",
    emoji: ""
  }
];
const j = [];
let arr = ["categoryDelete", "categoryNew"];

logs.map((m) => {
  arr.forEach((_) => {
    if (_ === m.value) {
      Object.assign(m, { default: true });
    }
  });
  return j.push(m);
});
logs = [...j];
console.log(logs);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, try not to dump code on it's own

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it was simple enough to just read. My bad